# How to save photos with custom name in cordova camera

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

Im wondering if there is a way to name the photos that I take with cordova camera, and if I can make like a search from the album, searching with the name, like photoName.jpg = mysearch

This is the service that I using to take the pictures.

```
        var _takePhotoOff = function(url) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            var options = {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit: true,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true
            };
            $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
                var photo = {
                    url: url,
                    photo: imageData
                }
                resolve(photo);
            });

        });
    }
```

Comment: https://devdactic.com/how-to-capture-and-store-images-with-ionic/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the name of the image from the plugin, but you will find the image info including the file name in the `imageData` object, and using `cordova-plugin-file` plugin you can access and rename the file.

Comment: @MarioVillalobos How did you resolve this? Is it cordova-plugin-file? If it is some other solution. Please comment or provide reference to the link

Comment: @ShrinuNamburu well im change most of my code, but the plugin-file had the way to change that
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html

Comment: @MarioVillalobos It will be very helpful if you could post your solution for renaming a particular file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

@Injectable()
export class CameraHandlerProvider {

  constructor(private camera: Camera, private filePath: FilePath, private file: File ) {

    }

    config = {
        quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    getPic(fileName: string) {
        this.camera.getPicture(this.config).then((imageData) => {
            this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imageData)
            .then((path) => {
                console.log(imageData, path);
                let imagePath = path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                let imageName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.length);
                this.file.moveFile(imagePath, imageName, this.file.dataDirectory, fileName)
                .then(newFile => {
                    console.log(newFile);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err);
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
}
```